# I want to use LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Wow! This is my first question in stackoverflow. And my english is not good yet.
I want to use LazyVerticalGrid. So I try to change compose_version to '1.1.1'.

```
e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.31 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

But I use Kotlin 1.7.0. Oh, tool is Android studio. I already checked android studio Kotlin version.

I changed
build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {

        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.6.4"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            compose_version = '1.1.1'
            kotlin_verison='1.6.4'
        }
    }// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

second error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

some scripts told me you have to changed dependencies. but how?...
Is there a secret to adding a dependencies that fits the error?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? There are two build.gradle files and you may have only changed the version in one of them and not the other.

Comment: I don't know it's the answer you want, but the version is fixed with '$compose_version'. And I brought all the chords. Help me @undermark5

Comment: no chords.... code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buildscript {
        ext {
            compose_version = '1.1.1'
            kotlin_verison='1.6.4'  >>>> Typo
        }
    }// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

you have a typo on `kotlin_version`

And on the first error, it tells you to use minimum kotlin version 1.6.10.

you just need to change this line from `version '1.5.31'` to  `1.6.10` or the newest version of it.

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
```

Comment: Thanks to you. The problem has been solved.